# Java and HID Communication

Tags: java, hid, hidapi

I'm looking to write a Linux/Windows/Mac Java HID controller for a simple wireless HID interface device. I've tinkered around with the USB4Java LibUsb library to no avail, and I've been steered in the direction of the JavaHIDAPI.

Unfortunately for me, I really have no idea what I'm doing beyond a pretty decent higher level programming skill set (C#/VB.Net), and switching over to this is killing me.

The [directions](https://code.google.com/p/javahidapi/wiki/ReadMe) that I found said that I would first need to compile the HIDAPI library found [here](https://github.com/signal11/hidapi/tree/master/windows). It said it would build something called hidapi-jni.dll (which it didn't).

Anyway, I think this is where I need to go since the HID does nothing but simply sends and receives signals to and from a wireless control (and responds to signals received).

Is there any step-by-step tutorial for using the JavaHIDAPI for this? Or is there a better library? (I noticed that this is a bit... dated).

I tried myself with the following:

```
static{ System.loadLibrary("hidapi"); }
.
.
.
public static void main(string[] Args) throws . . . {    
    ClassPathLibraryLoader.loadNativeHIDLibrary();
    HIDDevice dev = HIDManager.getInstance().openById(VEND_ID, PROD_ID, null);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

The issue into which I am running is that (besides the fact that the HIDAPI doesnt seem to be building into HIDAPI-jni.dll) is that the HIDManager.openById(. . .) always returns null. Also, I moved the hidapi.dll that was built into the C:...\Java...\bin directory... or something, I'm sure it's right because there wasn't any unsatisfied link error. It's really frustrating because there doesn't seem to be any newbies guide to Java and HID anywhere.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: confirm what `java.library.path` is

Comment: Are you talking about if it's defined in the system Path variable? I didn't see it in there.

Comment: java.library.path is the path that Java uses to find native libraries

Comment: alright... I don't know if this is correct but in the hidapi user library I created I defined (in eclipse) I defined the library to point to C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib.

Comment: is that in your path?  If not use -Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib

Comment: The windows environment path yes? It is now... and also, looking in the hidapi library I see a native folder containing a win folder with the hidapi-jni-64.dll file... could that be for what I am looking?

Comment: @Will I am having the same issue. Where do I start Java HID from? Do you know any good tutorials? I could find only this tutorial related to javahidapi https://code.google.com/p/javahidapi/issues/attachmentText?id=17&aid=170001000&name=PenTest.java&token=EEbb-hKn7SK4VN-vCbPFcWgxX4I%3A1345854892752 Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue, I discovered, was with native libraries.
I was able to get the application to work by copying the .dll from the .jar file and referencing it, but more important, I'm going to rebuild the .java class file responsible for loading the library and add the

```
System.loadLibrary();
```

call. When the `JavaHidApi` `ClassPathLibraryLoader.loadNativeHIDLibrary();` method is called it doesn't load the library upon successfully writing it out to the temp file which is mildly annoying. Doing this will eliminate the necessity for manually loading the library from a static location...

Thank you for pointing me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 7):

I'm a bit late to answer this question, but I've written a library called [hid4java](https://github.com/gary-rowe/hid4java) that might solve your problem.

It's based on Java Native Access (JNA) which is a lot simpler than faffing about with complex JNI incantations.

I had to write it because javahidapi is out of date and the underlying [signal11/hidapi](https://github.com/signal11/hidapi) code has moved on considerably. The older versions of the hidapi library had problems on OS X with attach/detach events which have now been fixed so an upgrade is necessary.

Also I found it impossible to claim a USB HID device through usb4java on OS X so I ended up writing this library to solve that problem.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Way late. I ended up going with Java HIDAPI and it worked fine. No need to go about reinventing the wheel. Thanks though.

Comment: Yes. It worked fine right out of the box, so to speak.

Comment: @GaryRower _Also I found it impossible to claim a USB HID device through usb4java on OS X_ you mean it was permanently "busy" because the Kernel's driver already had it. I'm facing some issues with claiming an HID interface via usb4java and I don't find the way to force the claim. The Libusb itself can not even solve if kernel already claimed it. What issues you had with usb4java and HID devices at the moment of claiming the interface?

Comment: @Laiv The usb4java doesn't seem to want to support HID so I ended up writing [hid4java](https://github.com/gary-rowe/hid4java) as a solution. I released version 0.6.0 to Maven Central today.

Comment: I know, I know. I did find first your project, then started to look for more info and this is how I found this post. I will try with HID4java then. Ty!

Comment: @GaryRowe just in case you have time. I posted my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62995533/issues-accessing-usb-devices-via-usb4javax-and-hid4java). where I also introduce an issue with your lib. I'm sure it's not a bug. It's  rather something I'm missing but I don't know what it's