# Is there any way to make my ps4 control vibrate/rumble? With java

Tags: java, joystick, gamepad, vibration

Maybe a library can do this? ;)

I have been searching the internet but can't find anything :(

I use glfw.

Comment: I use Jamepad which can do this.  https://github.com/williamahartman/Jamepad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dualshock 4 is tricky because it doesn't do rumble in a standard way. But, it's a HID device and you can send HID output reports that will cause it to rumble.

The easiest cross-platform way to send HID reports is to use the [signal11/hidapi](https://github.com/signal11/hidapi) library. From Java, you'll want a wrapper for this library like [hid4java](https://github.com/gary-rowe/hid4java), or you can take a look at what was suggested when this was asked [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796353/java-and-hid-communication).

Once you can access the device from Java and send reports, send a [0x11 output report](http://eleccelerator.com/wiki/index.php?title=DualShock_4#0x11_2) to tell the device to rumble.

As an alternative, since you're on Windows, you can use a third-party driver to make the DS4 look like an XInput device, and then send rumble commands through the XInput API. I would recommend getting [Ryochan's fork of the DS4Windows driver](https://github.com/Ryochan7/DS4Windows/blob/jay/README.md) since the original version hasn't been updated in a while. [See here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/82728/using-xinput-vibration-with-java) for how to use the XInput API from Java.